# How to generically extract field names and values in Haskell records

Tags: haskell, generics, record

I recently learned that I can do the following in Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data

data MyRecord = MyRecord
  { field1 :: Int
  , field2 :: String
  , field3 :: String
  } deriving (Show,Eq,Data,Typeable)

main = print $ constrFields (toConstr (MyRecord 5 "Hello" "World"))
```

This will give me the following:

```
["field1","field2","field3"]
```

**How can I do the same thing for the values in a record, like this:**

```
["5","Hello","World"]
```

I'm asking because I'm using `Aeson` to take simple JSON like this:

```
{
  "field1":5,
  "field2":"Hello",
  "field3":"World"
}
```

And generate Haskell code like this:

```
field1 :: Int
field1 = 5

field2 :: String
field2 = "Hello"

field3 :: String
field3 = "World"
```

How can I generically unwrap all the values in a given record in the same way I can unwrap the field names of my records?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to unwrap the JSON directly into `MyRecord`? Once you do, you can get at the values by calling `field1`, etc. on the record value.

Comment: I'm already deriving ToJSON and FromJSON for MyRecord, but I'd like to be able to unwrap all the values in the record without calling `field1`, `field2`, etc explicitly in order to access the values. I would like to just generically get all values in the form of a list of strings, just like I was able to do with the field names.

Comment: What would you expect as an output of such a function, your example already shows that a list would not work for your fields have different types. Same goes for Map String, also your field types can possibly have a nonshowable type like functions so a string representation is not generically possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first question can be answered. If you're happy to convert all the values of a datatype to strings, then you can indeed produce such a list with a generic programming library such as e.g. [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, FlexibleContexts #-}

import qualified GHC.Generics as G
import Generics.SOP

data MyRecord = MyRecord
  { field1 :: Int
  , field2 :: String
  , field3 :: String
  } deriving (Show, Eq, G.Generic)

instance Generic MyRecord

stringValues ::
     (Generic a, All2 Show (Code a))
  => a -> [String]
stringValues a =
  hcollapse (hcmap (Proxy :: Proxy Show) (\ (I x) -> K (show x)) (from a))

test :: [String]
test = stringValues (MyRecord 5 "Hello" "world")
```

Now in GHCi:

```
GHCi> test
["5","\"Hello\"","\"world\""]
```

However, if your goal is to maintain the original types, then this is more difficult, as the result type will have to be a heterogeneous list (which in fact `generics-sop` uses internally, before it is converted back into a normal list using `hcollapse`).

It's not entirely clear to me what you really want to achieve. It's quite possible that there's a much more straight-forward solution.

Comment: Cool example! Can the machinery in generics-sop be used to define extensible records a la [vinyl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl)?

Comment: @danidiaz In principle, yes. At least since `vinyl-0.5`, their `Rec` type is structurally isomorphic to `NP` in `generics-sop`. So conversion should be easy, and in theory, both libraries could be merged. But so far, doing extensible records has not been the primary focus of `generics-sop`.