# Dynamic field lookup with records in Haskell

Tags: haskell, records

I'm wondering if it's possible to get all fields of a record in Haskell that end with a certain name. For example

```
data Record = Record {
    field       :: String
    field2_ids  :: Maybe [Int]
    field3_ids  :: Maybe [Int]
}
```

In this case I would like to get a list of fields ending with "ids". I don't know their names. I only know that they end with "ids"
What I need is both the field name and the value it contains. So I guess this would be a list of maps

```
[{field2_ids = Maybe [Int]}, {fields3_ids = Maybe [Int]}...]
```

or even a list of tuples

```
[("field2_ids", Maybe [Int])...]
```

By the way, in my case the fields I'm extracting will always have the type of `Maybe [Int]`.

Is this possible? I suspect that it's not possibly with vanilla record syntax but is this maybe something that could be achieved with lenses?

UPDATE

I understand my question is causing some confusion in terms of what I'm actually trying to do. So I will explain

I'm using a microservice pattern with Services. Each Service is tied to a single data model. For example a Blog Service would contain a single Blog model. But the Blog Service can have all kinds of relations. For example it can have a relation to a Category Service. It can also have a relation to a Tag Service. Since there is a possibility of having more than one relation with another Service I have the type of a `Maybe [Int]` since I could be posting a Blog with `Just [Int]` or `Nothing`, no relations at all. Each Service handles its relations by registering them in a Relation table.

So to create a new Blog Post I need a data structure like this one in Servant

```
data BlogPostRequest = BlogPostRequest {
    title :: String,
    published :: DateTime,
    public :: Bool,
    category_ids :: Maybe [Int],
    tag_ids :: Maybe [Int]
}
```

The endpoint will take all the fields related to the Blog model and store it as a new Blog instance. It will then take all the relations if present in category_ids and tag_ids and store it in the Relation table.

My only concern about this, using the traditional record syntax is that if I have multiple relations, the code will get very bloated. Services are generated from config files. So yes I do actually know all the names of the fields from start. I'm sorry my statement about this before was very confusing. My point was that if I could pull the fields out of the record just by knowing that their names end with _ids I could reduce a lot of the code.

This would be the vanilla record syntax approach. Imagine that storeRelation is a method which takes a `String` and a `Maybe [Int]` and handles storing the relation accordingly

```
createNewBlogPost post = 
    storeRelation "category" (category_ids post)
    storeRelation "tag"      (tag_ids post)
    -- continue with rest of relations
```

This approach might not be so bad in the end. I would just add a new line for each relation. I was just wondering if there was a straight forward way to extract fields from records so that I could have the function like this

```
createNewBlogPost post = 
    storRelation $ extractRelations post
```

where storeRelation now takes a list of tuples and extractRelations is a function which extracts the fields ending with _ids

Comment: What would the resulting type be?

Comment: Do you just want the field names? Or the values from the record?

Comment: @chi the resulting type would always be the same. So The resulting type is I guess a list of maps? [{field_name = Maybe [Int]} ...]. jkeuhlen I would need both the field name and the values.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject, but this sounds like a job for [Template Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell), provided you know the suffix at compile-time.

Comment: Definitely a template haskell or generic programming problem. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369414/how-to-generically-extract-field-names-and-values-in-haskell-records

Comment: How is it possible that you don't know the field names, but you do know the type of the input record (i.e., Record)?

Comment: I actually know the field names. This process is simply to be able to write less code or to be able to combine functionality for multiple fields. But instead of doing record syntax to lookup each field which takes more lines of code I could combine it by getting all fields that end with ids and iterate through them. Maybe it's a overkill I guess I will see. But the fields I'm looking for are always a list of Maybe [Int]. These are id relations to other models in a database if it makes any sense

Comment: @Donna Why do you want to do this? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? I suspect this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You mentioned that the `Maybe [Int]`s are foreign key references: I can't think of any scenario in which you'd want to treat different foreign keys in a uniform way. They may be represented in the same way but they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I updated the initial post since I was not very clear about what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you actually do know all of the field names, and they are all of the same type, it should be quite a small amount of work to simply write each of the field names once, and much simpler than writing a big generic Template Haskell solution that would work for any data type.

A simple example:

```
idGetters :: [(String, Record -> Maybe [Int])]
idGetters = [("field2_ids", field2_ids), 
             ("field3_ids", field3_ids)]

ids :: Record -> [(String, Maybe [Int])]
ids r = fmap (fmap ($ r)) idGetters
```

It looks a bit ugly, but that's simply the best way to work with the data structure you're presupposing.

Comment: I agree, for a small number of field accessor, simple hard-coding is the most sensible approach. If it's more than a handful of these `_id` fields then I daresay the type was designed too monolithic in the first place and should better just have a single e.g. `all_ids :: Map String [Int]` field.

Comment: @leftaroundabout true. This is the approach I ended up with since I usually have under 10 fields with _ids. The thing is that this has to fit into the traditional HTML form approach, where you have a field for category_ids, a field for tag_ids etc. It would be possible to put them all together but I suspect it would require some work on the Javascript side which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 7):

I’ve come up with a complicated solution using `GHC.Generics` that seems to work. I’ve generalized the problem somewhat, writing a function with the following type signature:

```
fieldsDict :: (Generic a, GFieldsDict (Rep a) t) => a -> M.Map String t
```

Specifically, this takes a value of type `a`, which much be a record, and it produces a mapping from field names to values of type `t`. Fields that have a type other than `t` are ignored.

### Usage example

First, an example of what it *does*. Here’s your `Record` type from your question, along with a sample value:

```
data Record = Record
  { field :: String
  , field2_ids :: Maybe [Int]
  , field3_ids :: Maybe [Int]
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

exampleRecord :: Record
exampleRecord = Record
  { field = "a"
  , field2_ids = Just [1, 2]
  , field3_ids = Just [3, 4] }
```

Using `fieldsDict`, it’s possible to get all the fields of type `Maybe [Int]`:

```
ghci> fields exampleRecord :: M.Map String (Maybe [Int])
fromList [("field2_ids",Just [1,2]),("field3_ids",Just [3,4])]
```

To restrict the result to fields that end in `_ids`, you can just filter the resulting map by its keys, which is left as an exercise to the reader.

### Implementation

I’ll be up-front: the implementation is not pretty. `GHC.Generics` is not my favorite API, but at least it’s possible. Before we begin, we’ll need some GHC extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

We’ll also need some imports:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.TypeLits
```

The hardest part of making this work is being able to analyze which fields are of the desired type. To help with this, we need a way to “cast” `GHC.Generics` type representations, which we’ll represent with a separate class:

```
class GCast f g where
  gCast :: f p -> Maybe (g p)
```

Unfortunately, implementing this is hard, since we need to perform case analysis on `f` to see if it’s the same type as `g`, and if it isn’t, product `Nothing`. If we perform a naïve translation of that idea to typeclasses, we’ll end up with overlapping instances. To mitigate this problem, we can use a trick using closed type families:

```
type family TyEq f g where
  TyEq f f = 'True
  TyEq f g = 'False

instance (TyEq f g ~ flag, GCast' flag f g) => GCast f g where
  gCast = gCast' (Proxy :: Proxy flag)

class GCast' (flag :: Bool) f g where
  gCast' :: Proxy flag -> f p -> Maybe (g p)

instance GCast' 'True f f where
  gCast' _ = Just

instance GCast' 'False f g where
  gCast' _ _ = Nothing
```

Note that this means the `GCast` class only has a single instance, but it’s still useful to keep `gCast` as a class method instead of a free-floating function so that we can use `GCast` as a constraint later.

Next, we’ll write a class that will actually analyze the `GHC.Generics` representation of our record type:

```
class GFieldsDict f t where
  gFieldsDict :: f p -> M.Map String t
```

This allows us to define our `fieldsDict` function from earlier:

```
fieldsDict :: (Generic a, GFieldsDict (Rep a) t) => a -> M.Map String t
fieldsDict = gFieldsDict . from
```

Now we just need to implement the instances of `GFieldsDict`. To inform those instances, we can look at the expanded representation of `Rep Record`:

```
ghci> :kind! Rep Record
Rep Record :: GHC.Types.* -> *
= D1
    ('MetaData "Record" "FieldsDict" "main" 'False)
    (C1
       ('MetaCons "Record" 'PrefixI 'True)
       (S1
          ('MetaSel
             ('Just "field")
             'NoSourceUnpackedness
             'NoSourceStrictness
             'DecidedLazy)
          (Rec0 String)
        :*: (S1
               ('MetaSel
                  ('Just "field2_ids")
                  'NoSourceUnpackedness
                  'NoSourceStrictness
                  'DecidedLazy)
               (Rec0 (Maybe [Int]))
             :*: S1
                   ('MetaSel
                      ('Just "field3_ids")
                      'NoSourceUnpackedness
                      'NoSourceStrictness
                      'DecidedLazy)
                   (Rec0 (Maybe [Int])))))
```

Looking at this, we’ll need instances to drill down through `D1`, `C1`, and `:*:` before we get at the actual fields. These instances are fairly simple to write, since they just defer to more nested parts of the type representation:

```
instance GFieldsDict f t => GFieldsDict (D1 md (C1 mc f)) t where
  gFieldsDict (M1 (M1 rep)) = gFieldsDict rep

instance (GFieldsDict f t, GFieldsDict g t) => GFieldsDict (f :*: g) t where
  gFieldsDict (f :*: g) = M.union (gFieldsDict f) (gFieldsDict g)
```

The actual functionality will go in an instance on `S1`, since each `S1` type corresponds to the individual record fields. This instance will use our `GCast` class from earlier:

```
instance (KnownSymbol name, GCast f (Rec0 t)) => GFieldsDict (S1 ('MetaSel ('Just name) su ss ds) f) t where
  gFieldsDict (M1 (rep :: f p)) = case gCast rep :: Maybe (Rec0 t p) of
    Just (K1 v) -> M.singleton (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy name)) v
    Nothing -> M.empty
```

…and that’s it. Is this complexity worth it? Probably not, unless you can hide it in a library somwehere, but this demonstrates that it’s possible.