# Making Let binding parsing in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, interpreter

I want to create parser-like behaviour in Haskell such that I can assign an expression to a variable based on a string. I have difficulties doing so.

If I have types with the following definitions:

```
data Expr =
    Numb Int
  | Add Expr Expr
  | Let {var :: PVariable, definition, body :: Expr}

type PVariable = String
```

And want to create a function 'eval' that would be able to handle different operations such as Add, Subtract, Multiply etc... but also the Let binding, sucht that 'eval' would be subject to the following definition:

```
eval :: Exp -> Integer
eval (Number expr) = expr
eval (Add expr1 expr2) = eval(expr1) + eval(expr2)

...

eval (Let v expr1 body) = ...
```

How could I then create eval such that it would assign an expr1 to the string v, that would then be expressed in the body, such that the parser-like behaviour could accomplish for instance something similar to the conversion from:

```
Let {var = "Var1", definition = expr1, body = (Add (Var "Var1") (Var "Var1"))}
```

where expr1 would be a chosen expression such that the above could be expressed as

```
let Var1 = expr1 in expr1+expr1
```

That could then have different Expr assigned to expr1 such as (Numb 2), so that we would get something similar to the following in Haskell:

```
let Var1 = 2 in Var1 + Var1
```

So far I have tried to deal with isolating fields of the record 'Let' so that I can evaluate each of these considering that I want to stay with the function type declarations. But I don't think that this is the easiest way, and it would probably require that I create a whole function to extract these, as far as I can see from : [How to generically extract field names and values in Haskell records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369414/how-to-generically-extract-field-names-and-values-in-haskell-records)

Is there a smarter way to go about it?

Comment: You'll need `eval` to have some extra argument of type e.g. `type Vars = Map String Integer` and pass it around to subexpressions. `eval Let ...` would also modify it before passing.

Comment: Eh.... could you perhaps elaborate a bit more. So would I need to create extra types? Isnt there a way to do it without doing so?
I think the subexpression can be done recursively with eval itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the function `eval` to have extra argument that would contain the variable bindings and pass it to subexpressions recursively. You also need a special case to evaluate `Var`-expressions:

```hs
module Main where
import qualified Data.Map as M 

data Expr =
  Numb Int
  | Add Expr Expr
  | Let {var :: PVariable, definition, body :: Expr}
  | Var PVariable

type PVariable = String
type Env = M.Map PVariable Int

eval :: Env -> Expr -> Int
eval _ (Numb a) = a
eval env (Add e1 e2) = (eval env e1) + (eval env e2)

eval env (Var v) = M.findWithDefault (error $ "undefined variable: " ++ v) v env

eval env (Let v expr body) = let 
  val = eval env expr
  env' = M.insert v val env
 in eval env' body

main = print $ eval M.empty $ Let "a" (Numb 1) (Add (Var "a") (Numb 2))
```

Comment: Although I do consider your suggestion useful and correct, (and as similar to : https://youtu.be/lDWTNVfsvbk?t=673  I still think there would be a way to go about making the Let expression without introducing Env as another argument. The original definition that I posted of `eval` is part of an exercise wherein you also have to make a let statement. A similar function to the extended version you suggested is the task of the second part of that exercise. So I wager that would be a way to do so without dealing with Env.

Comment: No wait, actually I misread the exercise. The Let-expression is part of the full `eval(...)` which does take `Env` as an argument as well.

Comment: I shall try implementing your suggestion, and if I can make it work I will mark it as solved.